# Insert a blank record with some default values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm new to visual basic and trying to make a database application for a furniture company. I want to add a record with default values but I couldn't run my code for new item button. It behaves as if I didn't type any code. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click

    GondereninAdiSoyadiTextBox.Text = "Some text"
    GondereninAdresiTextBox.Text = "Some text"
    GondereninVergiNoTextBox.Text = "Some text"
    Label1.Visible = False

    Me.Refresh()

End Sub
```

How can I add code for BindingNavigatorAddNewItem?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I created another button with this code:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click

    MakbuzTBindingSource.AddNew()

    GondereninAdiSoyadiTextBox.Text = "Some text"
    GondereninAdresiTextBox.Text = "Some text"
    GondereninVergiNoTextBox.Text = "Some text"
    Label1.Visible = False

    MakbuzTBindingSource.EndEdit()

End Sub
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?408692-RESOLVED-Add-Item-binding-source